# Is there a word for "unnecessarily large"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to say:

> The utility produces *unnecessarily large* amounts of data, therefore most of it is discarded immediately.

The word should also, if possible, express the position that not only is the amount too large for me, but that it is too large for any reasonable use.

Comment: Forgot to ask. Are you using numeric / non-numeric data. I went through this process recently...

Comment: This does not answer the question directly, but I would rephrase this given it appears to be related to computing to say "The utility was verbose in its output, most of which was therefore discarded immediately." Given verbose is a very common term to refer to a program (or occasionally a person) which produces excessive output data.

Comment: **Overblown** output which renders the utility unwieldy to the point of uselessness. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overblown

Comment: I'm jotting down all the answers for future elevated "fat momma" jokes :D

Comment: Enormous. http://i.word.com/idictionary/enormous

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Excessive* seems perfect in your case. Otherwise *oversize* but that would apply more to an item than a mass of data.

Comment: “The utility produces excessive (amounts of) data” is absolutely perfect. “An excessive amount of data” in the singular sounds, for some reason, slightly less apt.

Answer (score 7):

[Superfluous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Superfluous) suggest the idea of excessive and unnecessary: (from TFD)

> - exceeding what is sufficient or required.

- the utility produces a superfluous amount of data.

Comment: Hmm … _superfluous_ to me means ‘**unnecessary** due to being in excess of what is required’, which is almost the same thing, but slightly different. The difference is what makes “a superfluous amount of data” sound odd to me—it’s not the amount that’s unnecessary, but the data itself. I would say simply, “The utility produces superfluous data”, though that might also be taken to mean that all the data produced by the utility is unnecessary or irrelevant.

Comment: Superfluous means more than is required, but suggests that a certain amount of it is required. It does fit this sentence quite well, but excessive (as per the highest voted answer) fits better

Answer (score 6):

The utility produces **a surplus of data**.

> surplus (noun) pl surpluses.   "an amount (such as an amount of money) that is more than the amount that is needed" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surplus).
>    - "an amount, quantity, etc., greater than needed" [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/surplus)

- There is **a surplus of workers** and not enough jobs.
- China's **trade surplus** has caused...
- Lake Cayor on the right side of the lower Senegal and Lake Panieful (Guier) on the left constitute reserve basins, receiving **the surplus waters** of the river during flood and restoring them in the dry season.

Comment: I think `surplus` fails to convey the second part of the request "too large for any reasonable use".

Comment: It does convey that. Just look at the definition and examples taken from mainstream dictionaries and the web.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *unwieldy* would also be an appropriate word here: "an unwieldy amount of data".

[One definition of the word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unwieldy) squares well with your requirement that the word should imply that the amount of data produced is a barrier to reasonable use:

> **Unwieldy:** Hindering progress because of complexity; hard to manage or deal with

Comment: There can be an unwieldy amount without it being unnecessarily large, however. It may be necessarily large...

Answer (score 2):

You might try ***overlarge***

[Defined in Oxford Dictionaries as](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/overlarge)

> Too large: *an overlarge meal*

Answer (score 1):

You might mean to say "..more data than I need...", implying that the utility may be perfectly suited to some tasks that require a lot of data, just not yours.  Said this way, you are not making a judgement that would seem to apply to every user of the utility.  Generally, if you are doing the latter it would be appropriate/useful to state why you think the problem of excessive data is a universal one.

Answer (score 1):

overly - which means excessively.

Answer (score 1):

How did no one else submit "Copious"?

adjective
abundant in supply or quantity.
"she took copious notes"

Answer (score 0):

unquantifiable?  Sprung to mind.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @OSFox. 
We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you edit your post to explain how it answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use (the rather slangy word) "overkill".

> "The amount of data this app produces is really overkill!"

Answer (score 0):

The utility produces *gratuitous* data; most of the data is unnecessary and so is discarded immediately.

Answer (score -1):

The word Over equipped could be used.

Comment: Hello, Charles. Over-equipped amounts of data? Over-equipped with data? A substantial rewrite would be necessary, and previous suggestions seem to fit the bill better.